# Trouble returning session data (user name)

Tags: php

I'm trying to integrate a php login script that I have working, but I can't seem to get simple php calls going on a page. On this user profile page, I want to simply have the user name displayed (mysql field is "name"). The user is logged in and the session carries through, but on this page, all I see is the text "Here is your profile info..." What might be wrong in the code to prevent the user name from displaying?

```
<?php 
    include_once('classes/check.class.php');
    include_once('header.php');

    if( protectThis("*") ):

    if(!isset($_SESSION)) {
        session_start();
    }

    if(isset($_SESSION['jigowatt']['name'])) {
       echo "You're name is: " . $_SESSION['jigowatt']['name'];
    }
?>


<br />
Here are is your profile info...

<?php 
    else : 
?>
<div class="alert alert-warning">
<?php _e('Only signed in users can view what\'s hidden here!'); ?></div>
<?php 
    endif;

    include_once('footer.php'); 
?>
```

Comment: please post the code where you create your sessions. i would like to introduce you to storing objects in a session and an easier OOP, way to work with those sessions.

Comment: Still down. Hard to say where I create my sessions. This is a large login program I purchased at http://envato.jigowatt.co.uk/demos/phplogin/home.php. It would seem that some class is keeping a perpetual session because there is always the built in user profile in the upper right where users can click on my account no matter what page they are on to see their info. But I need to create my own profile page and just can't seem to call the name variable from mysql properly. Sadly, there is no documentation really for this script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For check session is set already use `session_id()` Also check you have set `$_SESSION['jigowatt']['name']` already with `empty()`

```
if(session_id() == '') {
    session_start();
 }
if(!empty($_SESSION['jigowatt']['name'])) {
   echo "You're name is: " . $_SESSION['jigowatt']['name'];
}
else {
  echo 'username is empty';
}
```

Comment: Hmmm. Tried that and get the same thing...the header and then "Here are is your profile info..." and then the footer.

Comment: Hi Rakesh....this code you sent now returns "User name is empty"! So that's a start!

Comment: means $_SESSION['jigowatt']['name'] is empty so try to set value in it

Comment: OK....the below code now will show the username. However, it shows nothing for name (which is like a display name), and there is a value in the database for name. Not sure what is up. variable spelled right. But here is what works for showing the user name anyway: <?php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();

    if(isset($_SESSION['jigowatt']['username'])) {
    ?>
    <br /><br />
    <?php
    echo "You're username is: " . $_SESSION['jigowatt']['username'];
    }
    ?>

Comment: Very odd that it will display username with that code, but NOT name or bio or any other custom field, even though all these fields do populate the database upon registration. Oh well, I have a hunch you won't be able to help further without having all the files for this login program in front of you. If that is the case, many thanks for your efforts anyway. You're answer was correct if someone wasn't using this annoying login program and it's custom coding.

Comment: glad it's helpful for you . always accept/upvote helpful answer

Comment: Checking session state should be done using `session_status() != PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `session_start();` at the very top of the page. No white space can be put before that. Try if that works.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to write the sessions at the very top of the page if it works than okay else you can try this.

Just append this 2 function before and after the `session_start();`

Like this

```
ob_start();
session_start();
ob_end_clean();
```

Comment: Well, it's printing the "your name is:" part now at least. But still won't show the name variable for the user name. I tried just session_start(); and the ob_start();

Comment: This didn't work, but interesting. Never heard of ob_start function. Thanks.

Comment: Please look if the session is set and it also have the value which you wanted to pass on. Could you please paste the code where you are setting the session and its value or may b u can try to get the same value of the session variable on the page where you are setting the sessions.